# To look for subdirectories and perform some functions in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have written the following code to add some columns to the files in the subdirectory and to merge all the files in the directories,

```
 #!/bin/bash
 for sub in *
 do
   find . -name '*.bed' > log.txt
   while read path
   do
     filename=$(basename  "$path" | cut -d"." -f1)
     echo $filename
     awk -F'\t' '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t""'$filename'""\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7}' $path  > temp.dat
     mv temp.dat $path
     find . -iname '*.bed' -exec cat {} \; > $f.txt
     mv $sub.txt $sub.bed
   done < log.txt
   rm log.txt
 done
```

however the problem is that when I loop through the main directory it picks up the subdirectories as well as the files, I tried to apply the filter of checking if the $sub is a directory or not, however it seems to not work somehow.
So this is the file hierarchy
main directory-->subdirectories-->subsubdirectories-->files

Comment: Does passing `-type f` to `find` help?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to do (maybe include a tree and expected output tree). Your code isn't very clear (at least to me) and not obvious what "add some columns to the files" means.

Comment: `mv $sub.txt $sub.bed` doesn't make much sense. Guessing you want `for sub in *.txt` and `[[ -f $sub ]] && mv "$sub" "${sub%.*}.bed"`

Comment: You do not need `log.txt`.  You can use a pipe: `find . -name '*.bed' | while read ...` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Look:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 for sub in *
 do
   find . -name '*.bed' > log.txt
   # ...
 done
```

You are repeating the same `find` command over and over again, from the base directory. What you probably want to do is:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 for sub in */
 do
   find "$sub" -name '*.bed' > log.txt
   # ...
 done
```

In that way you will run `find` once for each subdirectory.

`*/` makes sure you only get directories as loop arguments, thanks [glenn-jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman)

**Edit:** And, as [David W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368630/david-w) and [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) point out, the outer loop and `log.txt` can be skipped by using this construct:

```
find */ -name '*.bed' -print0 | while IFS='' read -r -d '' path; do
   # Do stuff to $path as before ...
done
```

Comment: And use `for sub in */` to limit $sub to directories only.

Comment: You could simply do `find */ -name '*.bed` and eliminate the for loop!

Comment: if you're piping to read, better to use `find -print0` and `IFS='' read -r -d ''` to better deal with interesting filenames (containing newlines, backslash escapes and the like).

Comment: The whole script could probably do with a rewrite, but the obvious cause of OP's trouble was repeating the same `find` from the base directory.